# Update counter in slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, counter, carousel

I have a slider that I've built myself, which is a carousel that infinitely loops. I'm wanting to create a counter (1 of 4, 2 of 4) etc, with the last number being the total number of slides present and the 1/2/3/4 displays which slide you are viewing.

This is what I have so far for my counter:

```
var $tota = $('.past-project-container').find('span.total');
var $curr = $('.past-project-container').find('span.current');

function changeCurr(){
    $tota.text(numberOfProjects);
    $curr.text(1);
}
    changeCurr();
```

HTML:

```
<span class="slide-count-container">
   <span class="current">1</span> of <span class="total">1</span>
</span>
```

And this is my JS for the carousel if it helps

```
var $carousel = $('.past-project-slider'), carW = $carousel.outerWidth(), intv;
$carousel.wrapInner('<div id="slider" />');
var $slider = $('#slider');
numberOfProjects = $('.past-project-each').length;
$slider.css({position:'absolute',left:0, width:carW*numberOfProjects}).find('.past-project-each').css({'float':'left'});

function move(cb){
  if(!$slider.is(':animated')){
    if(cb=='next'){
        $slider.animate({left:-carW},800,function(){
            $slider.append($('.past-project-each:first'));
            $slider.css({left:0});
        });    
    }else{
        $slider.prepend($('.past-project-each:last'));
        $slider.css({left:-carW});
        $slider.animate({left:0},800); 
    }
  }
}

$('#next-past-project, #prev-past-project').click(function(){  
    var btn = this.id=='next-past-project' ? move('next') : move('prev');  
});
```

Many thanks,
R

Comment: I believe he is asking how to update the UI with the current slide each time it changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than constantly reading and converting the contents of the `$curr` element its probably better to keep track in another variable, like so:

```
var $tota = $('.past-project-container').find('span.total');
var $curr = $('.past-project-container').find('span.current');

var currentIndex = 0;

function changeCurr(){
    $tota.text(numberOfProjects);

    // If we've not reached the final index, add one, else return to the start
    currentIndex = (currentIndex == numberOfProjects) ? 1 : currentIndex + 1;
    $curr.text(currentIndex);
}

changeCurr();
```

This will count up until the last slide. Be sure to call `changeCurr()` on each slide transition.